# Why are deleted posts visible?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Just wondering why it is so? What's the catch? When I see that, then I feel as if I've seen something that the user did not want to publish, you know what i mean? The `delete` function is for removing entries and not to just mark it with red color?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: It's not deleted at all

[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

I think you will get all your answers there:

1. your rep grants you access to any deleted post/Q/A
2. you can always see your deletet items
3. all is true, until a SF employee deletes it from the DB :0-)

Comment: True, true... :) RTFM again got me :) Thanks!